# How to update an object in array using upsert?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, upsert

```
var newBillObject = {
    billId: Random.id(),
    billAmount: bill.billAmount,
    billDate: new Date()
};
var pointAdded = Math.round((bill.pointPercent / 100) * bill.billAmount);   
var data = Customers.findOne({ "phone": bill.phone });

if (data) {
    var restaurantInfo = {
        restaurantId: this.userId,
        points: pointAdded,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        lastVisited: new Date()
    };

    Customers.update({ "restaurants.restaurantId": this.userId }, {
            $push: { customerBills: newBillObject },
            $set: { "restaurants.$.lastVisited": new Date() },
            $inc: { "restaurants.$.points": pointAdded }    
        }, { 
            $setOnInsert: {
                "restaurants.$.createdAt": new Date()
            }
        },{ upsert: true }
    );
} else {        
    // return  
    // Customers.update({"restaurants.restaurantId":this.userId ,'phone':bill.phone}, {
    var restaurantInfo = {
        restaurantId: this.userId,
        points: pointAdded,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        lastVisited: new Date()
    }

    return Customers.insert({
        name: bill.name,
        phone: bill.phone,      
        code: bill.code,
        restaurants: [restaurantInfo],          
        customerBills: [newBillObject]
    });
}
```

I want to update an existing customer using upsert if `restaurants.restaurantId` `!= this.userId` but it's not updating that customer. Inserting a new customer and updating the customer whose `restaurantId==this.userId` is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you set upsert true in Meteor, you must have to put upsert in third curly brackets: like

```
Customers.update({
    "restaurants.restaurantId": this.userId
}, {
    $push: {
        customerBills: newBillObject
    },
    $set: {
        "restaurants.$.lastVisited": new Date()
    },
    $inc: {
        "restaurants.$.points": pointAdded
    },
    $setOnInsert: {
        "restaurants.$.createdAt": new Date()
    }
}, {
    upsert: true
});
```

Comment: I can see in you code you pass "upsert: true" in fourth bracket.

Comment: okk..Thanks.. btw do you know any method how to upload images in meteor on Amazon s3?

Comment: Have a look in this package : https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS

Comment: I had used this package. It is deprected. That is why I shifted to S3. Have you used it?